# some resources for a bianchi

Tags: road-bike, handlebars

I've got a 1981 (i'm told) bianchi 10-speed road bike. I am having trouble left and right. is there anything as basic as a site wherein i could provide the serial number and get some general information on the bike in return;, when it was made, the model maybe?

a lot of love for you guys, i'm new today and have a moderate amount of experience servicing bikes

Comment: Posting pictures here, including details of the components and any badges, might be a good start

Comment: As @srank says, post clear photos of the interesting bits after a clean and we'll tell you what we can.    You need to add more info to get a better answer... over to you.  Use the EDIT link to do this.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at [Sheldon Brown](http://www.sheldonbrown.com) to see what standards the Italians were using. Some things will work with standard British/ISO parts, other things won't. Notably, Italian bottom brackets are threaded in a nonsensical way. Asking specific question(s) about what's wrong is likely a better way to get help, given that at best, you'll be able to find a marketing magazine ad which won't be very useful for doing repairs.

Answer (score 3):

We don't usually supply lists of resources here, because they don't really fit with the general SE question-with-one-best-answer approach.

Interest in retro bikes and cycling gear is at an all time high, and so is the amount of information available.

I'm answering because I hope to give you, and others who end up here, an example of how this information can be found

In this case I Googled "[1981 bianchi catalog](https://www.google.com/?q=1981+bianchi+catalog)" (press enter after following the link) and got a bunch of hits.

The best seemed to be [Bianchi 1981 Catalog](https://saarf.london/2014/02/14/bianchi-1981-catalog/). It should answer a lot of your questions.

Many old catalogs have been digitized and can be found in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Bianchi Owners Club that is hosted on Facebook.  They often have "help me" posts and you will find a wealth of Bianchi die hards willing to assist you.